# wxWidget C++ wxString subscript

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to print subscripts or superscripts using if possible wxString or another wxWidget tool since my project heavily relies on wxWidgets.

It looks like it is done using UNICODE but there are lots of codes and I could not find the way I want. In an HTML code I want to print for example v<sub>f</sub>. Here 'f' is a single character and maybe there is a unique code for it. However, I want to learn the general way, if there is one, such as what if it was a string such as v<sub>astring</sub>.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Print" as in "print on paper" or as in `printf`, or as in display in a GUI window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to just display strings with sub/superscripts then the simplest solution probably is indeed to use `wxHtmlWindow`. If you also need to allow editing them, look at `wxRichTextCtrl`. You can't do it in general with just `wxStaticText`, although Unicode does have a few sub/superscript symbols, they're not exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

"In an HTML code I want to print for example vf."

Then you want the html sub and sup tags

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp

Comment: maybe I am misunderstood. I want to print on a wxstatic control. here f will be subscripted.

Comment: You cannot output html to a wxStaticText.

Comment: I know. However, how can I print something with a subscript to a wxStaticText. I know some characters can be printed by unicode. However, I want to learn if there is an easier way to do. That is all I want to know...

Comment: Then you should ask THAT question.  Please remove the reference to outputting HTML in your question which is so misleading.